# Two value in Many2one field odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

In Many2one field I Want view invoice name and invoice ammount_total how add this?

```
customer_invoice = fields.Many2one('account.invoice', 'Customer Inv', select=True)
```

Now after open customer_invoice field I view eg. INV/2017/0001, INV/2017/0002  I want INV/2017/0001 100€, INV/2017/0002 200€

Is it possible?

Comment: You have to add a `name_get` methode in invoice class

Comment: This methode change the default name

Answer (score 1):

This methode change the default name, just add it in invoice class

```
@api.multi
def name_get(self):
    result = []
    for record in self:
        name = record.name
        if record.ammount_total :
            name = record.name + ' ' + str(record.ammount_total)
        result.append((record.id, name))
    return result
```

Comment: Tnx for help, but I don't change in invoice class Is it possible change only in my custom modul for field in custom module?

Comment: Theb put it in your custom class, under `inherit account.invoice`